# My peerjs is creating too many client ids. How can I prevent this?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, multiple-instances, peerjs

Every time a user connects my peerjs terminal goes mad. This seems to impact my video stream as multiple videos appear. Here's an example of the output. How can I prevent this?

```
Client connected: 2eaceef7-f9ed-447e-9e2b-6317df92ecb8
Client connected: f7562550-cb63-42c4-b372-325ae4e7e086
Client connected: 54a49645-1fd0-4907-945c-6c658424c870
Client connected: 0f56f7f2-4cf1-4997-a628-4adf96dad2b2
Client connected: de8c1eef-fdbd-4a8e-8b10-4db2fb4deb35
Client connected: da68b0a7-f9ab-4387-a5a9-3ca0d4c6c9ef
Client connected: d1040068-6269-4ca7-af0d-ad89832cf270
Client connected: 0df6c0f7-35c5-484c-83c4-7999af0954f1
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { CopyToClipboard } from "react-copy-to-clipboard";
import { Peer } from 'peerjs';
import { useParams  } from 'react-router';
import "./Chaterio.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import styled from "styled-components";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:9000");

const VideoCall = () => {

  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [peers, setPeers] = useState({})
  const videoGridRef = useRef(null);
  const myVideo = useRef();
  const { roomId } = useParams();

  const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/', 
    port: 9001,
    concurrency: 1,
  });


  useEffect(() => {  

    console.log("useEffect started...")

    peer.on("open", (id) => {
      socket.emit("join-room", roomId, id);
      console.log("id ", id)
      setPeers({id})
    });
  
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    })
      .then((localStream) => {
        setLocalStream(localStream);
        if (myVideo.current) {
          myVideo.current.srcObject = localStream
          myVideo.current.muted = true
        };

        // receive calls by listening to the on call event
        peer.on('call', call => {
          call.answer(localStream)
          const video = document.createElement('video')
          call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            call.answer(userVideoStream)
             addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
          })
        });

        socket.on("user-connected", (userID) => {
          connectToNewUser(userID, localStream)
        });

        socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
          console.log("user-disconnected", userId)
          if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close();
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error getting user media: ", error)
      })

  }, []);

  

  const connectToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {

    // can make calls when new users connect to our room
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream)
    console.log("isserId ", userId)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', remoteStream => {
       addVideoStream(video, remoteStream);
    })
    call.on('close', () => {
      video.remove();
    })
    setPeers(prevPeers => ({...prevPeers, [userId]: call}))
    console.log("Print peers ", peers)
  };


  const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      video.play();  
    });
    if (videoGridRef.current) {
      videoGridRef.current.appendChild(video);
    }
  };



  return (
    <>
      <OuterContainer>
        <Header><AlinkHeader href="/">Chaterio</AlinkHeader></Header>
          <Container>
            <CopyToClipboard text={roomId} style={{ marginBottom: ".5rem" }}>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" >
                    Copy Room Id
                </Button>
            </CopyToClipboard>
          </Container>
          <VideoContainer>
            <VideoDrag >
              {localStream && <video id="myVideo" draggable="true" playsInline muted ref={myVideo} autoPlay width={500} height={500} />}
            </VideoDrag>
              <div id="video-grid" ref={videoGridRef} />
          </VideoContainer>
        
          <SectionOuterButtons>
              <SectionInnerButtons>

                  <a href="/"><RoomButton>Leave Room</RoomButton></a>
                  <a href="/room"><RoomButton>Join Room</RoomButton></a>

              </SectionInnerButtons>
          </SectionOuterButtons>
      </OuterContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It can’t be good to create a new `Peer` on every render, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This answer solves the multiple client Ids from peerjs and answers my original question.

I moved the const peer = new Peer() to a container file and passed it down as a prop. This ensures that a new client connecting gets one client Id passed down. The peerjs terminal also now only shows one Id per connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).